# "Let $\{x_n\}$ be a converging sequence such that $x_n>0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Show that $\lim x_n \geq 0$"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

"Let $\{x_n\}$ be a converging sequence such that $x_n>0$. Show that $\lim x_n \geq 0$"

Since $x_n >0$ there is a positive number $r$ such that $x_n - r = 0$. Let $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=a$ and $$\vert x_n - a \vert\leq\vert x_n-r\vert+\vert r-a \vert$$ $$\vert x_n - a \vert\leq\vert r-a \vert$$

Now if $n\to \infty$, we have that $x_n \to a$. Can I now claim that $\vert x_n - a \vert$ tends to zero, and as such $0\leq \vert r-a\vert$? After this we have three options for $r-a$, which would all ( quite easily ) show that $a\geq 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$x_n - r = 0$"? Are you claiming that is true for all positive integers $n$?

Comment: Yes. I think such a number $r$ must exist for each term $x_n$

Comment: Unless $\{x_n\}$ is a constant sequence, it's not true that there exists a number $r$ such that $x_n = r$ for all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x<0$. Then for $\varepsilon=|x|/2$ we find $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ it is $|x-x_n|<\varepsilon$. But then it is $-|x|/2<x_n-x<|x|/2$, so $x_n<|x|/2+x=x+(-x)/2=x/2<0$, a contradiction.